# Automapper unmapped properties error with simple objects mappings

Tags: c#, .net-core, mapping, entity-framework-core, automapper

I need to map a model object coming from API to my actual entity object on `DbContext`. It is used when creating a new machine object using a POST action.

As always, I created a simple map for the source/destination objects.
In this case we consider the source object as the API model and the destination object as the entity. Also the model has just a subset of properties of the entity.

#### Source/destination types

```cs
// Destination (entity on DbContext)
public class Machine
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MnmConfiguration { get; set; }
    public MachineBootStatus Status { get; set; }
    public long MachineDriverId { get; set; }
    public MachineDriver MachineDriver { get; set; }
    public string DriverConfiguration { get; set; }
    public string DriverStatus { get; set; }
}

// Source (from API controller)
public class MachineCreateModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MnmConfiguration { get; set; }
    public long MachineDriverId { get; set; }
}
```

#### Mapping configuration

```cs
public class DomainProfile : Profile
{
    public DomainProfile()
    {
        //CreateMap<MachineCreateModel, Machine>();
        // Update 2019/01/30 with proposed solution
        CreateMap<MachineCreateModel, Machine>(MemberList.Source);
    }
}
```

I'm using Unity DI container and the configuration of AutoMapper is this:

```cs
container = new UnityContainer();
// ... some other configurations...
container.RegisterType<IMapper, Mapper>(new InjectionConstructor(new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<DomainProfile>())));
```

#### Version

Using AutoMapper v8.0.0.

#### Expected behavior

I expect to obtain a simple automatic mapping without errors, since my source model is just a subset of properties of the destination model, with same names.

#### Actual behavior

I get this error about unmapped properties when I hit this line of code:

```cs
Machine entity = Mapper.Map<Machine>(request.Machine);
```

```
[14:08:34.363 8 2e62361a INF] Creating new machine: TEST M1
[14:08:36.205 8 bd577466 ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException:
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
=================================================================================================
AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
MachineCreateModel -> Machine (Destination member list)
MyApplication.Dcs.Application.Models.MachineCreateModel -> MyApplication.Dcs.Domain.Entities.Machine (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
Id
Status
MachineDriver
DriverConfiguration
DriverStatus

   at AutoMapper.ConfigurationValidator.AssertConfigurationIsValid(IEnumerable`1 typeMaps)
   at lambda_method(Closure , MachineCreateModel , Machine , ResolutionContext )
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object , ResolutionContext )
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TDestination](Object source)
   at MyApplication.Dcs.Application.Commands.MachineCreateCommandHandler.Handle(MachineCreateCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ..Commands\MachineCreateCommand.cs:line 28
```

#### Note

In my solution I've many projects and 3 of them are making use of AutoMapper (same version for all). There're 3 different `DomainProfile.cs` files (1 for each project) with the needed mappings.
In the other 2 `DomainProfile` classes I've some manual mappings (see example below) because I need to "translate" an object with italian property names to another one with english property names. So there're many lines for each object mapping, such as:

```cs
CreateMap<ArticleCreateUpdateModel, Articoli>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Categoria, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Category))
    .ForMember(d => d.CodiceArticolo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Code))
    .ForMember(d => d.Descrizione, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
    .ForMember(d => d.Famiglia, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Family))
    .ForMember(d => d.Note, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Note))
    ...
```

I don't know if the usage of those manual members mapping on one or more `DomainProfile` class, obliges me in some way to always explain all the subsequent mappings, even if they should be simple like those of this example.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, AutoMapper validates the destination properties. As there are neither matching properties nor `ForMember` constructs for a bunch of properties in your destination type you get the exception above.

Try to validate on the source properties instead:

```
CreateMap<ArticleCreateUpdateModel, Articoli>(MemberList.Source)
    .ForMember(d => d.Categoria, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Category))
    // ...
```

**Remark:**
On the other hand, I have to mention that this is the typical case when AutoMapper is an overkill. Apart from trivial cases I would never use it anymore.

I had to use it in a project for more than a year but actually it is only good for making simple things more complicated than necessary. Some `FromDto` and `ToDto` [extension] methods are just simpler, faster, easier to debug and more reactive to code changes. Mapping between different class layouts or property names often results practically as much code (or even more with tons of lambdas) as simply writing the mapping manually. See also [this link](https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/).

Comment: What about LINQ to Entities query projections? `ToDto` as being custom method cannot be translated to SQL and will lead to client evaluation / unnecessary entity tracking.

Comment: @IvanStoev: I prefer Entity with code first where there is no extra layer of generated model classes and the bulky EDMX xml files. But even if you have them you can avoid full client evaluation by calling `ToDto` explicitly _before_ executing any query. Meaning, all queries in some `Repository` class work on purely with the Entity model classes. One can argue that AutoMapper's `.ProjectTo` is nicer because no explicit mapping is necessary from outside but I think that in my `Repository` higher level classes must not be referenced at all.

Comment: @taffer I already tried with `MemberList.Source` using my model (DTO) as source and the entity as destination, but it didn't work. Anyway this is the first time I face those kind of problems. I've used AutoMapper (previous versions) in other projects and nothing like this has never happened.

Comment: @CheshireCat: You can even try `MemberList.None` to disable validation completely. You mentioned you used previous versions. Please also note that AutoMapper loves breaking changes in its new versions (the other reason I did not like it). I was not sure whether your `CreateMap` example was a fragment but be sure to use the newest way of configuration with `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap(...));`.

Comment: And just an additional note: The exception comes from `Machine` and not for `Articoli` so be sure to use `MemberList.Source`/`None` for that mapping as well.

Comment: @CheshireCat Besides the Remark section, this answer provides the solution of the problem you are describing. Saying "it didn't work" doesn't tell us anything. What "didn't work"? Can you prove that by providing [mcve]?

Comment: @taffer I see that you were referring to the wrong class but I used your proposed solution on `Machine` object mapping (see updated code above). My problem is with `Machine` object and `Articoli` was added within the **note**, just to show another existing `DomainProfile` class that exists in another project of my solution and to better describe my doubt about manual mappings.
@IvanStoev I've updated the code and also added a missing piece of configuration about `AutoMapper`.